# SQL exclude wildcard from WHERE

Tags: sql, where-clause, wildcard, sapb1

We've got a query on SAP which has some potential to cause problems.

```
SELECT 
T2.[DistNumber], T1.[ItemCode], T0.[ItemName], T0.[CardName], T2.[InDate], T1.[Quantity] 

FROM OITL T0  INNER JOIN ITL1 T1 ON T0.[LogEntry] = T1.[LogEntry], OBTN T2 

WHERE T2.[DistNumber] =[%0]
```

Somebody put the wildcard (%) into the prompt and of course everything got clogged up.

Is there a way to disallow the wildcard in the WHERE, maybe with a CASE or something?
The only other alternative I could come up with was to only select the top 1000 or something but I wondered if there was a better way.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you remove it in WHERE clause something like below?

```
SELECT 
T2.[DistNumber], T1.[ItemCode], T0.[ItemName], T0.[CardName], T2.[InDate], T1.[Quantity] 

FROM OITL T0  INNER JOIN ITL1 T1 ON T0.[LogEntry] = T1.[LogEntry], OBTN T2 

WHERE T2.[DistNumber] =replace([%0],'%','')
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks again